# Referencing Android XML resource file from variable

Tags: android

I have a XML file of error codes in the following format:

```
<resources>
    <string name ="e1001">"Description of error 1001"</string>
    <string name ="e1002">"Description of error 1002"</string>
...
</resources>
```

Normally these could be accessed in the usual way, i.e. `R.string.e1001`.

Is it possible to reference by using a variable in the reference, or will I have to use Xpath?

**This obviously doesn't work**, but something along the lines of:

```
String s = getErrorCode(); //returns a value, i.e "e1001"
showAlert(R.string.+s);
```

Comment: String s = context.getResources().getString(R.string.s);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within an `Activity`/`Fragment` you can get the `String` value of the resource by doing the following:

```
//Activity
String s = getString(R.string.s);

//Fragment
String s = getActivity().getString(R.string.s);
```

Your issue is not knowing that `R.string.s` returns actually returns as an `int`. Basically, it is a reference used by Android to determine the location of the string within your application.

`getString()` a method within the Context class - See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) for more

**EDIT:**

As per your comment, you will want to try the following:

```
String resourceName = getErrorCode();
String alert = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "string", getPackageName());
showAlert(alert);
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply Ed, getting the value from the resource file isn't my issue, what I am trying to do is dynamically pick a resource based on the contents of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this for Activity**

```
String s = getString(R.string.urresourcename);
```

> Try this for fragment

```
String s = getActivity().getString(R.string.urresourcename);
```